# Trouble with getchar()

Tags: c, getchar

I'm having trouble with the `getchar()` function. How do I distinguish if the user inputs a number larger than 10? I'm using     `int temp = value-'0';` to convert any number between 0-9 from `ASCII`. If you input 10 it returns 49 (ascii for 1). Help appreciated!

Comment: The `getchar` function gets a single character. If they type `10` , that is two characters. You will need to read (at least) two characters to detect this case.

Comment: A number larger that 9 would be 2 (or more digits) and would require multiple calls to `getchar()`. You need to show some more code.

Comment: Alright. I added more code. The reason I ask is because the assignment specifically requires getchar() to be used, aswell as handling inputs of 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getchar()` function only gives you a single character (or an end-of-file indicator), so you'll never get `10`, you'll get `1` then `0`.

If you want to input a *line,* look into `fgets()` or find a safe input function like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921).

Then you can use functions like `sscanf()`, `atoi()` or `strtol()` to process the line into a more suitable format, including error checking.

---

If you *must* use `getchar()` then it's a simple matter of maintaining an accumulator and working out the running value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void) {
    int ch, accum = 0;
    printf ("Enter your number (non-numerics will cease evaluation): ");
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (!isdigit (ch)) break;
        accum = accum * 10 + ch - '0';
        printf ("ch = %c, accum = %d\n", ch, accum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A sample run of this program follows:

```
Enter your number (non-numerics will cease evaluation): 314159
ch = 3, accum = 3
ch = 1, accum = 31
ch = 4, accum = 314
ch = 1, accum = 3141
ch = 5, accum = 31415
ch = 9, accum = 314159
```